# lsblk: Structure needs cleaning

Tags: linux, command-line

I ran a command to free up space, but while doing so, the command ironically ran out of space.

```
root@server:~# dd if=/dev/zero bs=4k | pv | dd bs=4k of=/dev/sda1
dd: error writing '/dev/sda1': No space left on device                                                                              <=>                                                                                                      ]
2096881+0 records in
2096880+0 records out
8588820480 bytes (8.6 GB, 8.0 GiB) copied, 77.2844 s, 111 MB/s
   8GiB 0:01:17 [ 106MiB/s] [                                                                                             <=>                                                                                                               ]
```

Now I cannot run any commands because the structure needs cleaning.

```
root@server:~# lsblk
bash: /bin/lsblk: Structure needs cleaning
root@server:~# ls
bash: /bin/ls: Structure needs cleaning
```

However the cat and df commands give a different message:

```
root@server:~# cat /proc/stat
bash: cat: command not found
root@server:~# df
Segmentation fault
```

Sources recommend to run fsck but I cannot because my system does not support the command:

```
root@server:~# fsck /
bash: fsck: command not found
root@server:~# fsck.ext4 /
bash: fsck.ext4: command not found
```

What is the recommended curse of action?

Answer (score 4):

> I ran a command to free up space,

That's not a command to free up space – that's a command to destroy all data on the 'sda1' partition. So while it's [technically true](http://bofh.bjash.com/bofh/bofh1.html) that you now have 8 GiB of free space, it also means you have nothing else left on the system.

> but while doing so, the command ironically ran out of space.

That message is expected here, as you're writing an infinite-length source (/dev/zero which keeps producing data forever) to a fixed-size destination (the /dev/sda1 partition which is exactly 8 GiB in size).

> [various error messages]

You get different error messages depending on which data happened to survive in the RAM cache kept by the OS, vs which data needs to be re-read from disk. Very recently used commands are still cached in RAM and will fail differently than those which haven't been cached yet. For example:

1. The OS can't even find the file, due to filesystem information having been erased. You get "File not found" (ENOENT).
2. The OS can still find the file based on cached directory information in RAM, but cannot read the file's own metadata (extent list) as it has been erased. You get "Structure needs cleaning" (EUCLEAN/EFSCORRUPTED).
3. The OS can open and read the beginning of the program which is still intact in RAM, but the remainder has to be loaded from disk, which either fails or returns garbage data due to having been erased. You get various crashes.

> Sources recommend to run fsck but I cannot because my system does not support the command:

It probably did up until you erased everything.

However, in the case where the `/` filesystem gets legitimately corrupted, the usual recommendation is to run fsck *from another system* (i.e. from a rescue liveCD), which will usually have all the necessary tools whether the original system had them or not. It'll also have greater flexibility in actually repairing the filesystem, since repairs often cannot be done while the filesystem is still mounted.

> What is the recommended curse of action?

The recommended curse is [omitted].

The recommended *course* of action is to restore the system from backups, or reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

To try to further explain:

> I ran a command to free up space, but while doing so, the command ironically ran out of space.

`root@server:~# dd if=/dev/zero bs=4k | pv | dd bs=4k of=/dev/sda1`

`of=/dev/sda1` here is addressing the entire first partition on the first disk with the name prefix "sd" (there may appear other prefixes, depending on where you connected the disk).
With fairly recent hardware 'sda' usually is the first disk. So here it is likely to be the system's bootable (root) partition.

Had you instead written just `of=/DUMPFILE`, that would[1] have been a very different matter; there would have been a zerofilled file (size as large as the OS had allowed) in the root of the disk, with all other files intact[2].

[1] if my guess in the previous sentence is correct that `/dev/sda1` *was* equal to `/`
[2] The DUMPFILE would have occupied all allocatable space on the disk, "cleaning" the contents of that portion of the disk. NOTE: This makes sense as a preparation; if you intend to "dd" the partition/disk into a compressed file (e.g. `dd ... | gzip -best backup.dd.gz`)